# How to overwrite values in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am reading in some data into a dataframe from an excel sheet. It looks something like this:

```
   ColumnA
0: abc-123
1: xyz-456
```

I want to get it like so where it takes everything before the dash from A and creates a new column B:

```
   ColumnA ColumnB
0: abc-123  abc
1: xyz-456  xyz
```

I have this but don't know how to go about overwriting each individual row:

```
df = pd.read_excel(some_file_path, some_sheet_name, parse_cols='A')
new_list = df('ColumnA')
for str in new_list:
    str = str.split('-',1)[0]

df.insert(1,'ColumnB', new_list)
```

but nothing gets overwritten, it just copies over the values exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a column assignment like this:

```
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnA'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:
    df['ColumnB']=[x.split('-')[0] for x in df['ColumnA']]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Slight edit to fix error, based on Quang Hoang's answer.

I'm not sure exactly what your dataframe looks like, but you could use the str.split method on Column A:

```
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnA'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

This returns:

```
    ColumnA ColumnB
0:  abc-123     abc
1:  xyz-456     xyz
```

Comment: I actually have more than one column in the df. How would I use that code above to insert it into the 2nd column exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; are you saying you want to split another column, or are you saying you want to split another part of ColumnA into a new column?

Comment: @thePandasFriend You can use `insert` to put the column where you want: `df.insert(df.columns.get_loc('ColumnA')+1, 'Column B', df['ColumnA'].str.split('-').str[0])`

Comment: So my df is made up of ColA, ColC, ColD in that order. I want to insert B into the slot so it goes A,B,C,D. I believe just calling the code you listed above will append it to the end

Comment: Sorry, I should've caught it sooner. But your code returns abc,123 in ColB. I was trying to get abc,xyz

Comment: I'm sorry about that.  Let me investigate why it's doing that.

Comment: Use Quang Hoang's method above: df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnA'].str.split('-').str[0].

Comment: You can always rearrange the columns like this: df = df[['ColumnA','ColumnB','ColumnC','ColumnD']].